# How to fill multiple div at regular intervals using jQuery in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Suppose I have an array which contains 2 itmes. Also I have 2 divs (mydiv1, mydiv2). First div has to be filled by first item of the array and second div has to be filled by the 2nd item of the array at the same time. And this process will repeat after regular intervals. I will keep on populating this array with new items by fetching from database, but that is out of scope of my question right now. How should I do this?

My xyz.php file is

```
<?php
//echo rand();
$questions=array(
                 "First Item",
                 "Second Item"
                 );
?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#mydiv1').load('xyz.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv1"> </div>
<div id="mydiv2"> </div>
</body>
```

Comment: PHP is server side, jquery client side. jquery doesn't know or care what you have got on server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JS:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('xyz.php', function(data) {
        $("#mydiv1").html(data[0]);
        $("#mydiv2").html(data[1]);
    });
}, 1000);
```

PHP:

```
$questions = array("First Item", "Second Item");
echo json_encode($questions);
```

Answer (score 1):

In you **xyz.php** file do

```
   <?php
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
    $questions=array(
                     "First Item",
                     "Second Item"
                     );

    echo json_encode($questions);
    ?>
```

Your **Index.php** file

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function () {
$.getJSON('xyz.php', function(data) {
    $("#mydiv1").html(data[0]);
    $("#mydiv2").html(data[1]);
});
}, 1000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv1"> </div>
<div id="mydiv2"> </div>
</body>
```